# apacheやnginxなどのサーバはどのような言語で動いているのでしょうか?

Tags: linux

プログラミング初心者です。

apacheやnginxってどのように作ってるのですか?
コンピュータ上でうごいているので何かの言語で作られてるのですよね?

CやJavaのような速い言語で作られてるのかなーと勝手に想象しています。

Webサーバだけでなく、メールサーバーなどを含め、こういったものは普通どのような言語で作られるのでしょうか。
規模や求められることによって変わってくると思いますが、教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

ソースをダウンロードして、中身を見てみるのがてっとり早いですね

例えば、Apacheであれば

http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi

nginx であれば

http://nginx.org/en/download.html

から、ソース一式がダウンロードできます。どちらも C で書かれていますね。

C 以外で書かれているものだと、たとえば Docker は Go 言語で書かれていたりします。

Comment: なるほど。
やはり一般的に使われる言語を用いてるのですね。
DockerがGo言語で書かれているのは興味深いです。

Answer (score 1):

ソケット通信に関わるプロジェクトは、ほとんどの場合C言語で書かれています。
Unixの亜種（Linux, FreeBSD, HP-UXなど）のほぼ全てで、ほぼ完ぺきな互換性を持つコードになるからです。
Windowsに移植するのも簡単です。

また処理速度が最優先事項になる場合が多く、そういった理由でもC言語が使われます。

処理速度が最優先事項なのは、例えば通常100台のサーバーが必要なところで、ソフトウェアが原因で120台サーバーが必要になったりすると、20台分のお金がかかるので誰も使わないからです。

逆に1台のコンピュータで済む（処理速度が重要でない）用途だと、どんな言語も使われています。

最近では、並列処理に関する問題が大きくなったため、それが原因でC言語に代わるプログラム言語が求められているようですが、まだ広く使われている言語は出てきていないと思います。